# Passing dictionaries to a Python script through the command line

Tags: python, command-line

How can I pass a dictionary to a python script from another python script over the command line? I use subprocess to call the second script.

The options I've come to are:
I) Build a module to parse a dictionary from a string (more in-depth than I had hoped to go).
II) Use a temporary file to write a pickle, and pass the file's name as an argument
III) Don't allow dictionaries, but handle key/value pairs (that is "prog.py keya valuea keyb valub")

The solution does not have to be user-friendly, but does need to be program friendly. The second program must be run as a separate process, due to security and resource concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from `pickle`, another option is `ast.literal_eval`, if your dictionaries only contain Python primitives.

```
>>> d = {3: 9, 'apple': 'orange'}
>>> s = str(d)
>>> s
"{3: 9, 'apple': 'orange'}"
>>> import ast
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> x
{3: 9, 'apple': 'orange'}
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module to pass the data over stdout/stdin?

Example:

knights.py:

```
import pickle
import sys

desires = {'say': 'ni', 'obtain': 'shrubbery'}
pickle.dump(desires, sys.stdout)
```

roundtable.py:

```
import pickle
import sys

knightsRequest = pickle.load(sys.stdin)
for req in knightsRequest:
    print "The knights %s %s." % (req, knightsRequest[req])
```

Usage and output:

```
$ python knights.py | python roundtable.py
The knights say ni.
The knights obtain shrubbery.
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need a too terribly complicated data structure, might I recommend [simplejson](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/)?  It's available as a built-in module (called `json`) in Python 2.6 and later.

Comment: Yeah, you can pass the json serialized dictionary by writing it to the stdin of the second script.

Comment: +1 because JSON is simple, effective, and almost identical to Python's `dict` structure.

Comment: +1 because this is perfect, although FoggleBird's answer is perfecter, and I can't talk the boss into anything that deals with javascript

Answer (score 2):

If what's in the dictionary (both keys and values) can be represented as strings, you should be able to pass it as a string argument to the second script which can recreate it.

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2}

d == eval(repr(d), None)

>>>True
```

**Edit:** Here's a slightly more involved example showing its use with a simple custom class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyClass(%r, %r)' % (self.a, self.b)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.a == other.a) and (self.b == other.b)

d = {'foo':42, 'bar': MyClass(17,'astring') }

print 'd:', d
print 'repr(d):', repr(d)
print "d == eval(repr(d), {'MyClass':MyClass})?:", \
      d == eval(repr(d), {'MyClass':MyClass})

# outputs:
# d: {'foo': 42, 'bar': MyClass(17, 'astring')}
# repr(d): {'foo': 42, 'bar': MyClass(17, 'astring')}
# d == eval(repr(d), {'MyClass':MyClass})?: True
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` can be too restrictive.  Instead of None, it's possible to pass `eval()` a second argument that is instead a dictionary mapping custom class names to corresponding custom classes which, when provided, would allow instances of them to also be reconstituted in additiona to the strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None value types that `ast.literal_eval()` supports.

Answer (score 0):

How about xmlrpc?

Client 
http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html

Server 
http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html

Both are in python core.

Comment: Seems like overkill for passing a `dict` around.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the dictionary in one python script

```
print( "dict=" + str(dict) )
```

and use it as

```
(python script1.py; cat script2.py) | python -
```

and now you should be able access the dictionary through global variable 'dict' in the second python script.